# Unable to send log messages form celery task to Sentry

Tags: python, logging, celery, sentry, raven

I'm having an issue logging to Sentry from within a celery task.  Errors in tasks work fine.  However, when I try to manually log an event, it gets logged to the celery logs, but not to the sentry server.

The code I'm using is:

```
@task
def myWorker():
  logger = logging.getLogger('celery.task')
  logger.addHandler(SentryHandler())
  logger.warn("Some condition happened", exc_info=True, extra={ 'extra': 'data' })
```

I've found some posts on here and around the net on this, but they all seem to be very out of date

Comment: Why `exc_info=True`? You're not in an exception clause, and `exc_info=True` indicates that traceback information should be written to the log.

Comment: Hi, @ChrisBurnor. Any news on this ancient issue?

Comment: Try printing (or otherwise inspecting) the loggers from within the task. Most likely it's not picking up the correct config.